# Serialize the field from Scriptable in another Scriptable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have found an interesting "issue" in UnityEditor regarding Scriptable objects. Below is simple example:

I have scriptable class ScriptableExpressionBulder that holds some list and a float field.  Then I have another class ScriptableExpressionCreator that holds a LIST of scriptable objects mentioned previously. The code looks like this:

```
public class ScriptableExpressionBuilder : ScriptableObject
        {
           public List<MultipleExpressionBuilder> multipleExpressionBuilder;
           public float delay;
        }



public class ScriptableExpressionCreator : ScriptableObject {

        public List<ScriptableExpressionBuilder> List;

}
```

When creating ScriptableExpressionBuilder the fields from (MultipleExpressionBuilder) comes up nicely but it also adds a second field "delay" at the end (which is perfect to this point).

Now for the interesting part:

The second class ScriptableExpressionCreator holds a list of previous scriptables but it doesn't serialize the "delay" field in this current scriptable. The only field that is serialized is a Scriptable class.

Is there a way to serialize the field from ScriptableExpressionBuilder in another Scriptable that holds a list of these scriptables so I can basically set the delay from where this expressions are called. I could however populate the field in the inspector of original scriptable, but the wouldnt be reusable since each delay is different.

Comment: That's no issue ... The Inspector draws an object field for `ScriptableObject` (and anything else that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object`) ... if you want to draw something else you would need a [custom editor script](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html)

Comment: Basically I would need to draw "Delay" field from ScriptableExpressionBuilder to a ScriptableExpressionCreator. I need custom inspector for this? Is there another way I could create a delay between ScriptableExpressionBuilder files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the question deleted but I voted to reopen it since I already had started to write the solution and finished just when you deleted it and I think this now does what you want and gives you a good start point for further extending it where needed ;)

That's not really an issue, however, not possible built-in.

For `ScriptableObject` (and anything else that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object`) the Inspector by default draws an object field. If you want to draw something else you would need a [custom editor script](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html). There is not really away around customizing the Inspector in order to expose fiels of other `UnityEngine.Object` references in the Inspector of another one.

It could look somewhat like e.g. (for now assuming you only want the `delay` field to be exposed additionally)

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ScriptableExpressionCreator))]
public class ScriptableExpressionCreatorEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _list;

    // I know ... but that's your fault for naming th field List :P
    private ReorderableList _listList;

    // For Edito this is called when the object gains focus and the Inspector is loaded for this scriptableobject instance
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Find and link the serialized field called "List"
        _list = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ScriptableExpressionCreator.List));

        // Initialize and configure the ReorderableList to draw the referenced elements in the way we want
        _listList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _list, true, true, true, true)
        {
            // How is te list header drawn?
            drawHeaderCallback = rect => EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, _list.displayName),

            // how should each element be drawn?
            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, active, focused) =>
            {
                // get the current element
                var element = _list.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                // draw the default object reference field with the height of a single line without the label
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), element,  GUIContent.none);

                // if no object is referenced do nothing more
                if (!element.objectReferenceValue) return;

                // move one line lower
                rect.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                // get a serializedObject of the reference
                var elementsSerializedObject = new SerializedObject(element.objectReferenceValue);

                // same as in our own OnInspectorGUI method below loads the current values
                elementsSerializedObject.Update();

                // for now assuming you only want the delay field
                var delay = elementsSerializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ScriptableExpressionBuilder.delay));

                // draw the delay field
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), delay);

                // same as in our own OnInspectorGUI method below writes back changed values and handles undo/redo marking dirty etc
                elementsSerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            },

            // how do we get the height of one element?
            elementHeightCallback = index =>
            {
                // get the current element
                var element = _list.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                // if nothing is referenced we only need a single line
                if (!element.objectReferenceValue)
                {
                    return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                }

                // otherwise we need two lines, one for the object field and one for the delay field
                return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2;
            }
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // draw the script field
        DrawScriptField();

        // loads current values into the serialized version
        serializedObject.Update();

        // draw the list according to the settings above
        _listList.DoLayoutList();

        // writes bac any changed values into the actual instance and handles undo/redo marking dirty etc
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    // Draws the default script field on the top the Inspector
    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        // The script field is disabled since nobody is supposed to evr change it
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromScriptableObject((ScriptableExpressionCreator)target), typeof(ScriptableExpressionCreator), false);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        // leave a little space between the script field and the actual inspector conten
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
}
#endif
```

For now this would look like this

[image]

Comment: Hey, I actually deleted the question because I found an alternative that kinda works, however it looks that your solution is way better after I gave it a second thought. Thank you for this, you're a godsend. +1 for all the explanation comments on what the Editor does.